# Spring JPA : applicationContext.xml can not create entityManagerFactory bean

Tags: mysql, spring, jpa, eclipselink

I use Spring 3.2.0, JPA 2 AND my IDE is SpringToolSuit 3.1.0.
When I run Test class (main class) I get this exception, I googled but I can not find any solution.

```
Exception in thread "main" org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in class path resource [applicationContext.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.reflect.UndeclaredThrowableException
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1486)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:524)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:461)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:295)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:223)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:292)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:194)
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBean(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1117)
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:922)
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:479)
at org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.<init>(ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.java:139)
at org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.<init>(ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.java:83)
at com.first.form.Test.main(Test.java:17)
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.UndeclaredThrowableException
at $Proxy3.addTransformer(Unknown Source)
at org.eclipse.persistence.jpa.PersistenceProvider.createContainerEntityManagerFactory(PersistenceProvider.java:213)
at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.createNativeEntityManagerFactory(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:286)
at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:310)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1545)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1483)
... 12 more
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
at org.springframework.orm.jpa.persistenceunit.DefaultPersistenceUnitManager$Jpa2PersistenceUnitInfoDecorator.invoke(DefaultPersistenceUnitManager.java:617)
... 18 more
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot apply class transformer without LoadTimeWeaver specified
at org.springframework.orm.jpa.persistenceunit.SpringPersistenceUnitInfo.addTransformer(SpringPersistenceUnitInfo.java:109)
... 23 more
```

applicationContext.xml is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-3.2.xsd">

<bean id="entityManagerFactory"
    class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean">
    <property name="persistenceUnitName" value="testJPA"></property>
</bean>

<tx:annotation-driven />

<bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager">
    <property name="entityManagerFactory" ref="entityManagerFactory" />
</bean>
<bean id="persistenceAnnotation"
    class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.support.PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor" />

<bean id="userDao" class="com.first.dao.UserDAOImp"></bean>
</beans>
```

persistence.xml is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence version="2.0" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_0.xsd">
<persistence-unit name="testJPA" transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">
    <provider>org.eclipse.persistence.jpa.PersistenceProvider</provider>
    <class>com.first.entity.UserInfo</class>
    <properties>
        <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/test"/>
        <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.user" value="root"/>
        <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.password" value="xxxxx"/>
        <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.driver" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"/>
    </properties>
</persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

Test class:

```
package com.first.form;

import org.springframework.context.ApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext;
import com.first.dao.UserDAO;
import com.first.entity.UserInfo;

public class Test {

/**
 * @param args
 */
public static void main(String[] args) {

    ApplicationContext applicationContext = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("applicationContext.xml");
    System.out.println("****     "+ applicationContext);
    /*UserDAO userDao = (UserDAO) applicationContext.getBean("userDao");

    UserInfo userInfo = new UserInfo();
    userInfo.setName("name");
    userInfo.setFamily("family");
    System.out.println("User names is: " + userDao.getAllUsers());
    userDao.createUser(userInfo);*/
    System.out.println("User is successfully created");

}

}
```

Comment: do you have persistence.xml in META-INF folder of classpath?

Comment: yes its path is: src\META-INF\persistence.xml

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The correct entityManagerFactory should be :

```
<bean id="entityManagerFactory"
class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalEntityManagerFactoryBean">
<property name="persistenceUnitName" value="testJPA"></property>
</bean>
```

By this factory we do not need "loadTimeWeaver".

Answer (score 2):

Try adding

```
<property name="loadTimeWeaver">
    <bean class="org.springframework.instrument.classloading.InstrumentationLoadTimeWeaver"/>
</property>
```

Please check [here](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/orm/jpa/LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.html#setLoadTimeWeaver%28org.springframework.instrument.classloading.LoadTimeWeaver%29) for more details about weaving for JPA

Comment: blob thanks for your reply,it help me to find solution.Again thanks

Comment: Can you specify where to add this?

Comment: LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean implements LoadTimeWeaverAware, hence you need to set LoadTimeWeaver while defining its bean

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively ,try adding this to your JVM start parameters

-javaagent:C:/jars/spring-instrument-3.0.4.RELEASE.jar ( or latest version)